# Zend routing (default controller to handle all url)

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

At first sorry for my poor English.
I want to handle all requests which do not match with my routes to `CustomPageController`.

I am trying to configure my `module.config.php` like this:

```
'defaults' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/*', // or 'route' => '/user*' for example, to handling www.site.com/user4 (just as example)
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'custom_page',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

To handle all queries that do not match with routes must redirect to my last "defaults" route. But it is not working.

Comment: Can you post you Custom Page Controller?

Comment: CustomPageController has only indexAction(){} with echo 123; die; now.

Comment: I think your controller name is CustomPageController and in your module.config.php you are calling custom_page, So i think you must replace it with CustomPage along with full path if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `ErrorController` as an alternative for this. If the controller name is not found then you get the error code 500. You can then do whatever you want to do on that controller (re-route to your `CustomPageController`)